# Openlitespeed error 400 with Nginx proxy manager in front?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

So, i have a server running Nginx Proxymanager that handles all incomming http/https requests and SSL termination towards a Cyberpanel server running Openlitespeed. As i recently updated Cyberpanel, a update for Openlitespeed happened aswell.

After this update all my websites in Cyberpanel logs an error of 400

Like this:
`2023-08-18 13:53:20.562546 [INFO] [21429] [192.168.9.131:36602] Status 400: Invalid charactor in header name: 'X-ForProto -Proto'`

As i understand it, it's mostly related to my Nginx proxy manager config of     `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;` as this is the only thing i can find related to "Proto".

Could anyone please explain a solution to this problem as im shot blank and not used to these kinds of issues (Simple homelab owner)

It seams i can't edit the config from within the Nginx proxymanager UI it self and have to do a rebuild? (Maybe) Im not a solid Docker user either so some basic instructions and maybe an explanation wold do me good at this point. Maybe i need to understand the problem deeper in order to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

I have been trying to reconfigure and uncommenting proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-Proto $scheme; with no luck, either i end up with 503 or a blank page. Cache have been cleared and both server have been restarted.

I have also created a tread over at Cyberpanel forums with no luck since yesterday.